# Upgrade Joomla 1.7.3 to 2.5.0 failed

Tags: php, xml

I need to migrate my joomla 1.7.3 site to joomla 3.
So, I first upgraded it to joomla 1.7.4 and 1.7.5 successfully.

In the next step I am going to upgrade it to 2.5.0. So I downloaded the update package for joomla 2.5.0 from: 
http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5403-joomla-250-released.html

But unexpectedly installing this package fails by error "Failed loading XML file".

I extracted the zip file and noticed that it does not contain joomla.xml file. Could this be the reason? If not, how can I handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the page you mention, you're getting a very old and buggy version.

http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19396/158841/Joomla_2.5.x_to_2.5.20-Stable-Patch_Package.zip

This is the full 2.5.20 update package.

make a backup of your site & db.

Then extract this package over your current installation;

then go to the administrator/extensions/database and press "fix" to update the database accordingly.